# Hibernate - Getting count of all records a in given month

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, dao

I am new to spring boot and hibernate. I was able to build simple API to get all records using FindAll and similarly was able to add few filters as well like findAllByName. However, now I am stuck because I have a need for more complex data.

User.java

```
import java.util.Date;
import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

private long id;

private String name;
    
private int age;

@CreationTimestamp
private Date createdOn;

}
```

Database Example

```
Table 1 - User
Name   Age Created On
Mike   23  2023-07-10 22:55:25.787000
Akshay 53  2023-06-25 21:15:25.787000
Bheem  43  2023-07-07 08:25:25.787000
Rahul  33  2023-06-11 12:55:25.787000
Gin    33  2023-05-10 01:55:25.787000
```

I have two users who got created in July, two in June, and 1 in May. I need to create a hibernate dao query to find number of records for each month. In this example I should get - July =2, June =2 and May = 1. How do I do that?

Comment: After getting the list returned by `findAll()` function, perhaps you can create `ArrayLists` of all months you need to count, loop through the list checking months of `createdOn` and add  records to arraylists eg if date is July add that record to July's arraylist. After looping then you check sizes of arraylists  which will be equal to number of accounts created that month